# Парсинг данных с сайта на свой сайт wp

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет.столкнулся с такой проблемой.Делаю сайт с билетами, но хочу запарсить на него данные. Не подскажете как лучше реализовать вывод?Может есть уже плагин или готовое решение?
Использовал плагин, который парсит контент, но он выводит их в виде xml файла,и изображения там в формате ссылки, то есть надо открывать каждую и смотреть.Не очень удобно, кто нибудь решал уже подобную проблему?

данные хочу взять с этого сайта http://minskconcert.by/afisha/vse-kontserty
1)изображение
2)Тайтл
3)дата и расписание события

есть плагин,который грузит все в водпресс(но он кривовато работает тоже,то как отдельные страницы грузит, то в посты,в идеале,чтобы грузило как на том сайте,на одной странице)

выводы данных должен быть в экселевском файле.если есть готовые решения будет супер

Comment: лучше из бд, фото с диска, по плагину не скажу, но ты же нашёл 1, доработай его, пусть он в бд сохраняет а не в файл

Comment: сам сайт на вордпресс. ищу плагин,который бы парсил данные вообще с другого сайта.не моего.данные чтобы парсились в любую точку сайта

Comment: ну, понятно, что не с твоего парсить нужно. Укажи хотя бы с какого "другого" сайта плагин должен парсить может и подскажут

Comment: данные хочу взять с этого сайта http://minskconcert.by/afisha/vse-kontserty
1)изображение
2)Тайтл
3)дата и расписание события

есть плагин,который грузит все в водпресс(но он кривовато работает тоже,то как отдельные страницы грузит, то в посты,в идеале,чтобы грузило как на том сайте,на одной странице)

Comment: как ты можешь заметить, желающих писать парсер тебе особо тут нет, попробуй на кворке заказать, очень вероятно, что в 500р. уложишься.

Comment: да я и не прошу никого писать.есть дофига готоых решений.думал,у кого то остались они